# JSP form doesn't send to database. Using beans

Tags: java, sql, database, forms, jsp

When i submit data from my form it doesnt save to the database... no error occurs...

i can retrieve from the database but not save to it...

heres the code:

test.jsp

```
 <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="my.beans.StudentBean"%>

<jsp:useBean id="studentData" scope="request"
             class="my.beans.StudentDataBean"/>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Words View</title>
        <style type="text/css">
               table, tr, td, th
               {
                    text-algn: center;
                    font-size: .9em;
                    border: 3px groove;
                    padding: 3px;
                    background-color: #eee9e9;
               }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Student List</h1>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <h4>First Name</h4>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <h4>Last Name</h4>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <h4>Comment</h4>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <h4>Email</h4>
                </th>
                </tr>
                    <%
                        ArrayList<StudentBean> studentList = studentData.getStudentList();
                        Iterator studentListIterator = studentList.iterator();
                        StudentBean student;

                        while (studentListIterator.hasNext()){
                            student = (StudentBean) studentListIterator.next();
                    %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= student.getFirstName()%></td>
                    <td><%= student.getLastName()%></td>
                    <td><%= student.getComment()%></td>
                    <td><%= student.getEmail()%></td>
                </tr>
                <% }
                %>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

formTest.jsp

```
<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>


<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<jsp:useBean id = "student" scope = "page"
             class = "my.beans.StudentBean" />
<jsp:useBean id = "studentD" scope = "page"
             class = "my.beans.StudentDataBean" />

<html>
    <form method="post" action="test.jsp">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>Student Login</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <jsp:setProperty name = "student" property = "*" />
            <% // start scriptlet
                if (student.getFirstName() == null
                        || student.getLastName() == null
                        || student.getEmail() == null
                        || student.getComment() == null) {
            %>
            Enter forename, surname, student ID and email address to <br />
            register.<br />
            <br />
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="first" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="last" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="email" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Comment:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="comment" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </form>
    <%            } else {
        studentD.addStudent(student);
    %>
    <jsp:forward page="test.jsp" />
    <%
        }
    %>
</html>
```

And then my beans...

StudentBean.java

```
package my.beans;


public class StudentBean {

        /***********\
         * Globals *
        \***********/

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String comment;
    private String email;

        public StudentBean(){

        }

        // get/set for First Name
    public void setFirstName(String f) {
        firstName = f;
    }
        public String getFirstName(){
                return firstName;
        }

        // get/set for Last Name
    public void setLastName(String l) {
        lastName = l;
    }
        public String getLastName(){
                return lastName;
        }

        // get/set for comment
    public void setComment(String co) {
        comment = co;
    }
        public String getComment(){
                return comment;
        }

        // get/set for Email
    public void setEmail(String em) {
        email = em;
    }
        public String getEmail(){
                return email;
        }
}
```

StudentDataBean.java

```
package my.beans;



import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl; // CachedRowSet implementation

public class StudentDataBean {

   private CachedRowSet rowSet;

   // construct TitlesBean object 
   public StudentDataBean() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
      // load the MySQL driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      // specify properties of CachedRowSet
      rowSet = new CachedRowSetImpl();
      rowSet.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"); 
      rowSet.setUsername("root");
      rowSet.setPassword("");

      // obtain list of titles
      rowSet.setCommand("SELECT firstName, lastName, email, comment FROM guests" );
      rowSet.execute();
   } // end StudentDataBean constructor

   // return an ArrayList of StudnetBeans
   public ArrayList<StudentBean> getStudentList() throws SQLException{
      ArrayList<StudentBean> studentList = new ArrayList<StudentBean>();

      rowSet.beforeFirst(); // move cursor before the first row

      // get row data
      while (rowSet.next()){
         StudentBean student = new StudentBean();

         student.setFirstName(rowSet.getString(1));
         student.setLastName(rowSet.getString(2));
         student.setEmail(rowSet.getString(3));
         student.setComment(rowSet.getString(4));

         studentList.add( student ); 
      } // end while

      return studentList;
   } // end method getStudentList

   // insert a Student in student database
   public void addStudent(StudentBean student) throws SQLException
   {
      rowSet.moveToInsertRow(); // move cursor to the insert row

      // update the three columns of the insert row 
      rowSet.updateString( 1, student.getFirstName() ); 
      rowSet.updateString( 2, student.getLastName() ); 
      rowSet.updateString( 3, student.getEmail() ); 
      rowSet.updateString( 4, student.getComment() ); 
      rowSet.insertRow(); // insert row to rowSet
      rowSet.moveToCurrentRow(); // move cursor to the current row
              try{
            rowSet.acceptChanges();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception caught at line 67: " + e);
        } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong. The formTest.jsp always have null values for student details the first time it is loaded and the else block for adding the student never gets called. So on what scenario do you expect it to fall into the else block?

Comment: its been sorted now but cheers anyway man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: it was an error with my java conventions not matching.